# If the sum of three primes is equal to a prime ...

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Does anyone know how to always get a prime from the sum of three primes?

For example: $5+7+11=23$, $17+29+43=89$, etc.

Answer (score 4):

It has long been [conjectured](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_weak_conjecture) that every odd number greater than $7$ is the sum of $3$ primes. It is known that every large enough odd number **is** the sum of three primes.  I do not know of any extra information known if the target odd number is itself prime.

If your question has to do with an efficient *algorithm* for finding the $3$ primes, I know very little. But it turns out that for large odd $n$, there seems to be a large number of representations of $n$ as a sum of three primes, so an efficiently conducted search works reasonably well.

Comment: Nicolas: Thanks for the information. I have done extensive work on the Goldbach conjecture and I have developed a new method for the presentations of primes. The material can be found on MO. Most likely I will present the material again in the near future. Sometimes we obtain millions of representations of an odd number as a sum of three primes.

Comment: @VassilisParassidis: Then nothing I wrote is new to you! Sorry, I did not know.

Comment: It has been proven in 2013 (which I see is after you wrote this answer).